# ReactDom.hydrate removes SSR DOM

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-dom-server

In the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#hydrate), it says, `React will attempt to attach event listeners to the existing markup.`
So I thought that if I use ReactDOM.hydrate, it'll only add events.

```js
// server.js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const html = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('./build/index.html'), 'utf8');

    return res.send(
    html.replace(
      '<div id="root"></div>',
      '<div id="root">hihi</div>',
    ),
  );
}
```

```js
// index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.hydrate(
    <App/>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

```js
// App.jsx
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

export default () => {
  return <Title>Hi !</Title>;
};

const Title = styled.h1`
  color: blue;
`;
```

However when the hydrate works, it removes DOM created by SSR and replaces it with DOM created by CSR(react script)

[image]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

That is not how React SSR works . You should have react at the server side as well and probably you can use renderToString on server side for that. This way react will know this is server rendered react node and needs hydration over client side.

Answer (score 0):

Your server rendered `HTML` is,

```
<div id="root">
    hihi
</div>
```

And your client rendered `HTML` is,

```
<div id="root">
     <h1 style="color: blue;">Hi !</h1>
</div>
```

First, the browser loads the server `HTML`. Then the client starts to rehydrate over the server-rendered `HTML` which is significantly different compared to client rendered version. Therefore, it removes the `hihi` text and then adds the `h1` element to the DOM. Thats why you see the flickering when you refresh the page. You can change your server `HTML` as below to fix your issue.

```
// server.js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const html = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('./build/index.html'), 'utf8');

    return res.send(
    html.replace(
      '<div id="root"></div>',
      '<div id="root"><h1 style="color: blue;">Hi !</h1></div>',
    ),
  );
}
```

When you try to do a real project then you need to use `ReactDOM.renderToString` inside the server side. There are plenty of artcle to get started. Please check this => https://medium.com/bucharestjs/upgrading-a-create-react-app-project-to-a-ssr-code-splitting-setup-9da57df2040a

Comment: @Jeong Ho Nam, if this cleared your concern, can you please mark this as the answer?